# Before CLI, what interface was used to program computers?

Tags: interface, history

**NOTE:** I looked through all of the other Stack Exchange Tech sites, and couldn't find a better place to post this question. If you believe that there is a preferable site, feel free to migrate the question.

As I have been working through the CLI on my Raspberry Pi, I have begun to wonder what was used before the CLI. How were computers programmed without even a rudimentary interface? And how did we go from that ancient interface to the CLI, and eventually the GUI?

Thanks!

Comment: Flip switches and punch cards come to mind, but I'm sure there were others

Comment: CS might be a good place for this question, but I think that's generally more theoretical. Since the `history` tag exists here, I'd guess this is not off-topic.

Comment: There are tons of good books on the history of computers and computing.  Also check out the Computer History Museum web site.

Answer (score 3):

Before the CLI: Patch cords.  Front panel lights and switches.  Punched cards.  Punched 35mm film.  Punched sheet paper. Paper tape.  Magnetic pencil dots on paper. Analog knobs and dials.  Initial gear positions.  And that's just a partial list.